# Coming up with names for 4 children

Tags: fiction, naming, child-characters

I am looking for character names to design a personality for 4 children in my story.

Comment: Are you asking for character names for the superheroes (LaffyTaffy Lad, Mister Butterfingers) or the kids (Bob, Aki, Gaetano)?

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum  I am looking for both.

Comment: Closing; this isn't a question that's answerable in any way but a list of opinions. I'm glad you got some helpful suggestions, but our site [tour] may help clarify how Q&A sites differ from discussion forums.

Comment: Existing posts on the site: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/138 , http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/16936

Comment: The answer really depends on the type of names you're looking for. You could you a tool like http://thenamestork.com to set a general name 'feeling' and get matching recommendations.

Comment: Or if you know the feeling you want, [fantasynamegenerators.com](https://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/) is always a useful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of candy is it?  Are there different flavors?  Were the candies the same that all four kids ate?

You could do different colors/flavors perhaps.  And the different flavors make for different superpowers.

Here are some ideas:

- Red Juiceberry
- Turquoise Taffy
- Green Slimesuck
- Crack Caramel
- Red Poprock
- Roasted Poprock
- Salted Chew
- Sweet Purpleblast
- Flavorblast

Are these what you're looking for?  The candies could also bring out the kids' natural personalities.  For example, if one of the kids had a bad temper, it could enhance that trait and make him extremely fiery (lots of attitude, anger issues, etc.).

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for.Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of 3 rhymed names and a discordant one. A retro example would be

Inky, Blinky, Pinky, and Clyde (Pac-Man)

And a modern example (from Nickelodeon):

Nicky, Ricky, Dicky, and Dawn

These sorts of things flow well with children's characters.