# How to make the first lines of my novel attractive and hooking?

Tags: fiction, fantasy, reviews

I am currently writing a fiction/fantasy/horror novel, and I have only written some pages.
I have published the first part of the novel especially for *this* question.

How can I make my first lines attractive, suspenseful, hooking...?
You can read what I have written by [clicking here](http://vivastemcell.com/enigma.htm).

Comment: Three hours and your link already returns a 404. You'd best fix that before site curators close your question as spam.

Comment: For reference to your question, though - take a look at this: http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/107/16

Comment: I fixed the web site link, sorry, I had forgotten the .html extension.

Comment: New link doesn't work either. I suggest you either remove the link and any reference to it in your question, or fix the link and add the "reviews" tag into the question. Might be seen as SEO spam, otherwise. Based on the first answer below, you may want to consider the first option. My 2c.

Comment: Now it works, really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive a first sentence from a story?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35826/how-to-derive-a-first-sentence-from-a-story)

Comment: I was going to say "still doesn't work" but then I saw the date on the conversation :P The critique part would be off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooking lines make the reader ask one or more of the following questions:
**What? Why? How? When? Where?**

A good example are the stories of [Blind Willow, Sleeping Woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_Willow,_Sleeping_Woman) by [Haruki Murakami](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruki_Murakami) (yes, I'm sick of the "Call me Ishmael", and the "they shot the white girl first" examples).

*"Man-Eating Cats"*

> I bought a newspaper at the harbor and came across an article about an
>   old woman who had been eaten by cats.

**What** the f...? **How** can a bunch of cats eat a woman?

*"The Ice Man"*

> My husband's an Ice Man

An iceman? **How** and **where** did she meet him?

*"Nausea 1979"*

> Thanks to his rare talent for keeping a diary over an extended period
>   of time without missing a single day, he was able to cite the exact
>   date his vomiting stopped.

**Why** did he vomit for so long? **What** was the cause?

*"A Shinagawa Monkey"*

> Recently she'd had trouble remembering her own name.

**How** can someone forget his/her own name?

Good hooking sentences make the reader ask one or more questions without causing too much confusion. They cause wonder and provide information and at the same time in a perfect, balanced way. The worst you can do is to leave the reader thinking: *So what?*

**EDIT**

I checked your link.

> Stars… I look at them, dream of them… They are so close, and yet, so
>   far… They sparkle like tiny fireflies on the dark canvas of the bluish
>   sky. The horns of the half-moon have newly vanished out of sight from
>   the horizon, leaving behind them tenebrous ash. It seems the moon is
>   looking at me with its silver-shining beam. I suddenly remember my
>   great-grandfather’s old telescope of which my mother told me about an
>   epoch ago (I might be exaggerating). His death was very enigmatic.
>   Nobody knew how he disappeared. Nobody saw his cadaver.

Everyone look at the stars and dream of them, and it doesn't raise any **what, why how...** question. Not a good hooking sentence. Consider this:

> Watching the stars, I suddenly remembered
>   great-grandfather’s old telescope of which my mother told me about an
>   epoch ago.

**What** is so special about the telescope? **How** come he still remembers it?

or

> My great-grandfather's death was very enigmatic.
>   Nobody knew how he disappeared. Nobody saw his cadaver.

**How** did he die? **Why** was his death enigmatic?